# zeromq message pattern for many to many request/reply

Tags: zeromq

I'm very new to ZeroMQ.  I've read the guide and am currently going through the examples as well as looking at other relevant info around the web.  I'm having some indecision with what message pattern(s) to use or if I should use a combination of 2 patterns.

I have an existing software application that has a home grown messaging system that is in need of replacement.  I have a fairly simple architecture:

```
|Client|<----->|driver1|
           |
           |---|driverN|
```

Only one "client" connects to a driver at a time currently, and there may be many drivers.

(in actuality, the client, in this case, isn't truly my client application, but a middleman of sorts.  For this discussion, it can be treated as a client)

Messaging:

1. The client issues commands to the driver.
2. The drivers return status/state information in response to commands.
3. The drivers produce data elements (i.e. Not status/state information)
4. Some Client messages go to all connected devices, some are directed only to a single driver.

Drivers may exist on the same system or remotely on a LAN.  This is not a public network.

I'm currently thinking that I would have a pub and sub socket on each driver and a sub/pub socket on the client.  Messages shouldn't be dropped once a connection is made.  I assume that the client would subscribe to the different driver data types and the driver would then subscribe to the clients command messages.

Important considerations:  low latency, lowest possible bandwidth overhead.

I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm with you on 1, 2, and 4, but lost on 3; the driver produces data elements, ok, but what's the message exchange required? Also, on 4, does the client decide if a message goes to a single device or all devices? Is the client a ZeroMq client?

Comment: for 3, the data produced is in response to a command sent by the client.  Example:  client sends a command of "Take still image" and the driver then returns an image.    For 4, the client decides which device(s) to talk to.  The client will have a zeroMQ component.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Start by reading http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Chapter-Advanced-Request-Reply-Patterns, you'll need that background to understand request/reply semantics and enveloping. I suggest playing with the examples too, it's the best way to learn. I'll post some code samples tomorrow for this problem.

Comment: I've read the guide.  twice.  I'm concerned about the extra overhead of REQ/REP in my particular system. I've been going through the examples, etc...  Having trouble getting a few of the examples to build, but I understand the general concept of most of them.  I appreciate the feedback and the upcoming code samples!

Comment: What language binding you using? BTW, can clients address devices using a logical name, like `printer1`, `scanner5`?

Comment: this is all in C.  Although I convert to C++ if need be.  I can have clients address via a logical name or just straight ip/port.

Answer (score 7):

You picked a great learning exercise, that's for sure!

Read up on these, they provide the basic implementation for request/reply using a custom router-to-router proxy with polling and should address your client-to-device problem.

- https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/lbbroker.c
- https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/lbbroker2.c

The solution is synchronous, so any request sent from the client blocks until it gets a response. Personally I would use async for both request and reply for total flexibility, but that solution is way more complex. There are, however, examples in the book called `Freelance` and `Dealer/Router` that illustrate async request/reply.

Here's an example for synchronous many-to-many request/reply. You MUST know how ZeroMq enveloping works to fully understand the mechanics of this approach; see example [lbbroker1](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/lbbroker.c).

## Client

Set the client identity with `setIdentity()`; important for response routing.
Client sends requests for `device1`, `device2`, etc, in a loop; if device exists, status messages returned from specific device, otherwise, "no device" returned to client.

```
    Socket client = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    client.setIdentity("client1".getBytes());
    client.connect("tcp://localhost:5550");

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       client.send("device" + i);   
       String reply = client.recvStr();
       log("Received message: " + reply);
       Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
}
```

## Device

Device sets id just like client for unique routing.
Device sends `device.send("DEVICEREADY")` to server to signal online availability.
Device does `recvStr()` three times to read full envelope from server.

```
String deviceId = "device1"
Socket device = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
device.setIdentity(deviceId.getBytes());

device.connect( "tcp://localhost:5560");
device.send( "DEVICEREADY");

while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   String clientAddress = device.recvStr();             
   String empty = device.recvStr();
   String clientRequest = device.recvStr();

   //create envelope to send reply to same client who made request          
   device.sendMore(clientAddress);
   device.sendMore("");
   device.send( "stauts on " + deviceId + " is ok");
}
```

## Server (Router/Router)

A custom proxy using ROUTER sockets; clients connect to frontend ROUTER socket while devices connect to backend router. Server polls on both sockets for messages.

```
Context context = ZMQ.context(1);       
Socket frontend = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
Socket backend = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
frontend.bind( "tcp://localhost:5550");
backend.bind(  "tcp://localhost:5560");         

Poller poller = new Poller(2);  
poller.register(frontend, Poller.POLLIN);
poller.register(backend, Poller.POLLIN);

while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   poller.poll();

   //frontend poller
   if (poller.pollin(0)) {
      String clientId = frontend.recvStr();
      String empty = frontend.recvStr(); //empty frame
      String deviceId = frontend.recvStr();

      //if client is requesting to talk to nonexistent deviceId,
      //return message "no device", otherwise, create envelope and send
      //request on backend router to device.
      if( deviceMap.get( deviceId) == null ){
         frontend.sendMore(clientId);
         frontend.sendMore("");
         frontend.send("no deviceId: " + deviceId);
      } else {
        //request envelope addressed to specific device
        backend.sendMore(deviceId);
        backend.sendMore("");
        backend.sendMore(clientId);
        backend.sendMore("");
        backend.send("hello from " + clientId);
       }
   }

    //backend poller  
    if(poller.pollin(1)){
       String deviceId = backend.recvStr();
       String empty = backend.recvStr();
       String clientId = backend.recvStr();

       //device signaling it's ready
       //store deviceId in map, don't send a response
       if( clientId.equals("DEVICEREADY"))
           deviceMap.put(deviceId, deviceId);

       else {
           //the device is sending a response to a client
           //create envelope addressed to client, send on frontend socket
           empty = backend.recvStr();
           String reply = backend.recvStr();
           frontend.sendMore(clientId);
           frontend.sendMore("");
           frontend.send(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would love to see it!  I'm proficient in Java. I'm trying to learn as much as possible about this before I stick myself with a bad design...